# Android Custom Dialog not Showing

Tags: android, customdialog

I want to show a simple custom dialog. For starters I simply wanted to add a text view and see if the dialog show.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvPreview" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/Instructions"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code for the onCreateDialog Function:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.predialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Tests of my Dialog");
    return dialog;
}
```

When the user (me) presses a menu item the I use this code:

```
public void DiagTests(){
    showDialog(0);
}
```

What happens is that the screen obscures but the dialog doesn't show.

Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

PD: Just in case there are no errors or warnings of any kind.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach. Create a Custom Dialog class (this is an example of a class, you can use what you want):

```
/** Class Must extends with Dialog */
/** Implement onClickListener to dismiss dialog when OK Button is pressed */
public class DialogWithSelect extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {

private String _text;
Button okButton;
Button cancelButton;
/**
 * ProgressDialog that will be shown during the loading process
 */
private              ProgressDialog            myDialog;

public DialogWithSelect getDialog() {
    return this;
}

public String getText() {
    return this._text;
}

public DialogWithSelect(Context context) {
    super(context);
     myDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getContext());
     myDialog.setMessage("Exporting file...");
    /** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the title */
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_with_select_box);

     final Spinner hubSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSelectFormat);
     ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this.getContext(), R.array.spinner , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     hubSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);
    cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);

      okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
            //whatever  
            }

        });



    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Get the text from the texString to paint on the Canvas
            getDialog().hide();
        }

    }
);


}
```

Define the dialog on the class where it is going to be used:

```
final DialogWithSelect dialog = new DialogWithSelect(getContext());
dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialogSelectBoxText);
```

And launch it in the click event:

```
dialog.show();
```

Comment: I actually got it to work! However it was strange. I created a completely new project just to test this custom dialog thing and it worked on my first try, because I didn't carry the xml over (I created it from scratch). So what I did is generate the xml from scratch and it worked. Thanks for the help. Although it would be very interesting to know what was it that was wrong with it...